# Tell Emacs never to insert Tabs

Tags: emacs

I know how I can make it so that hitting  doesn't insert a tab, but spaces.

However, Emacs keeps using tabs for indentation, like:

```
space space
space space space
tab tab space space
tab tab tab space space space
```

It's a messy mix, how can I configure it so that it *never* inserts tabs, for anything?

Comment: What version of emacs was this for?

Comment: Emacs still does this by default, in 9 years later, in version 26.1. It's bizarre, since there's no standard that says how many spaces a tab is wide.

Comment: @Ant6n my understanding is that Emacs will basically never change default behavior (the charitable perspective is that this would be a surprising breaking change since most people don't actively go out of their way to explicitly set every setting to its default value, and there are probably many people who rely on and expect this particular behavior).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

Answer (score 10):

Check the variable `indent-tabs-mode`. If you set it to `nil` then `emacs` will use spaces to indent to the `tab-stop` when you press `tab` and never convert spaces to tabs.

Comment: I know this is old, but there is no real difference between this and the accepted answer of ten points; only the final step of actual implementation.  +1 for some *why* as opposed to *how* (which can be *easily* derived).